# "Open to" or "open on"?

Tags: word-usage

You're in an elevator. Does the door open ***on*** the 4th floor or ***to*** the 4th floor?

You're on the 4th floor waiting for the elevator. Does the door open ***on*** you or ***to*** you?

I can go on with other examples, but is there a general rule?
Does it matter if "open" is used as an adjective or a verb?

Answer (score 2):

The elevator door can open *on* or *to* the fourth floor. Both are grammatical:

> The elevator door **opens on the third floor**, we emerge and walk our separate ways.

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ny2u7bHeTPYC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=%22the%20elevator%20door%20opens%20on%20the%22&source=bl&ots=8HiLKyMQmA&sig=-QorA1PW0KZRYks-Oc2JkcQosqE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAmoVChMI8PWekbWLyQIVh9QOCh0g7QP3#v=onepage&q&f=false))

> The elevator door **opens to the second floor**. She looks back at the elevator. The tall suited man is still there.

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=DvJvE52XaS0C&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22the%20elevator%20door%20opens%20to%20the%22&source=bl&ots=E16Uj94U_c&sig=x9r3ga01Y1_4F_6zLccOgE3eIpg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMIutSciLWLyQIVBn8PCh2kBgCG#v=onepage&q&f=false))

*You're on the 4th floor waiting for the elevator. Does the door open **on** you or **to** you?*

When talking about an elevator door, I'd say neither. The elevator door opens **before** you, or **in front of** you.

Comment: The far elevator doesn't stop at every floor, but does open **onto** the sixth floor.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a difference in meaning. On your last sentence, if you search in Google Books, you'll find examples like: _The one who knocks will always have the door opened to him_.

Comment: @MJF Your example (*The one who knocks...*) is perfectly grammatical, of course. I was talking about an elevator door, I've edited my answer for clarity. Regarding the difference in meaning: in the elevator examples given, I think the only tangible difference is that "to" indicates direction, while "on" indicates location.